# Easiest and most secure way to call a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Im building a website based on asp.net MVC, with a web api which allows me to upload and edit content through a windows program i also wrote. 
So there is, and will only be 1 windows client, that needs to communicate with the web api.

I dont know anything about security, but before i dig in, and read alot about it, i wanted to hear which solution to go with (that is fairly simple, but still secure)

I've been looking a little into ssl and self-signed certificates, but that seems kinda overwhelming right now.

Since i only have 1 client and 1 website, would it be a disaster to hardcode something (like just adding a string field to the DTO's which is called "key" and some hardcoded key. Or mayby some kind of encrypt/decrypt algorithm?)

What do you guys think?, How would you come around this?

EDIT: Forgot to say that once in a while, the website will also contact the windows client, which is through a simple TCP server/client connection. This connection ofcouse also need to be secure

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

Comment: Yes, i've seen this. But this doesnt help me find out which solution i should go with, since its a list of solutions.. And furthermore this is the "correct" solutions, would it be okay (work and be secure) to hardcode my way out of it

Comment: _What_ do you want to secure and how?

Comment: Im sorry if that is not clear. I want to make sure, that nobody from the 'outside' can access the windows client or web api. So that some stranger cant upload or edit content.